# How to update an array passed as a parameter on init when new items are added on the original array

Tags: arrays, swift, pointers, reference

Say for example I have an array that needs to be used on multiple classes, if I need a worker to update the values of this array how do I make it so that when I add new values to the said array the object worker's value also changes.

Example:

```
class Object {
    var id: Int
    var foo: String
    var bar: Int

    init(id: Int, foo: String, bar: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar
    }
}

class ObjectWorker {
    var objects: [Object]

    init(objects: [Object]) {
        self.objects = objects
    }

    func updateObjects(withId id: Int) {
        self.objects.forEach { $0.foo = "a different value" }
    }
}


class SomeClass {

    // this declaration will happen on more than one class
    var objects: [Object] = ... // let's just say there are 10 objects here
    lazy var worker = ObjectWorker(objects: self.objects)

    init() {
        // to initialize the workers
        _ = worker

        print(objects.count) // 10
        print(worker.objects.count) // 10

        let newObjects: [Object] = ... // let's say this has 5 new values
        objects.append(contentsOf: newObjects)

        print(objects.count) // 15
        print(worker.objects.count) // 10
    }
}
```

I have tried making the `ObjectWorker`'s init be an `inout` parameter like this `init(objects: inout [Object]` but even then the result is still the same. The `updateObjects` works though even if the `init` is not an `inout` parameter.

**Note**:

1. I know I can do this by using the `ObjectWorker` as the container of the objects instead of what is currently going on in here, but is there a way to do this without doing that?
2. I can also use static functions instead, but let's not go there

Comment: Don't keep a separate array. Only have the array in `ObjectWorker`. Read that one array. Update that one array. Then anyone with a reference to that same instance of `ObjectWorker` will have access to that one array.

Comment: @rmaddy I know I can do that, see note #1. Is there a way to do this behaviour without doing that?

Comment: Not using a Swift array since such an array is by value, not reference.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, Swift Arrays are value types so ObjectWorker gets a copy of the array. If you don't want to use ObjectWorker as a container, you could use an NSArray instead (which is a reference type).